# volume of water in the the pool and domain range of function question

Tags: calculus, volume, geometry

im working on advanced problems and the question is following:

A swimming pool is 20 ft wide, 40 ft long and 3 ft deep at the shallow end, and 9ft deep at its deepest point.

1) Express the volume of the water in the pool as a function of height h of the water above the deepest point (Hint: The volume will be a piecewise-defined function)

2) Determine the domain and range of the function found in part (1)

how should I approach this type of problems? I haven't learned about this topic yet so I'm not sure if I'm on the right track

Volume (at full capacity) = V 
V = 0.5 (length)(deep end depth + shallow end depth)(width) 
I'm stuck after this..

The answer is given for 1) its piece-wise defined function(sorry I don't know how to do latex)

how do I get this answer? step by step explanation would be very much appreciated thank you

Comment: See the MathJax basic tutorial for how to effectively typeset questions and answers: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Does the pool depth vary uniformly from 3-9'?

Comment: @copper.hat yes I guess it varies uniformly from 3ft to 9ft

Comment: I suspect you have a typo in the first line.  The 9 feet should be 8 feet based on the 5's in the answer.  Have you thought about the shape of the water?  At depths less than 5 feet you have a shape with a rectangular bottom and a ridge top.  When the depth passes 5 feet, the sides become vertical and you need to add a box for the volume.

Comment: I would expect the ranges to be $[0,6]$ and $[6,9]$. I would expect a $h^2$ dependence in the first range and a $h$ dependence in the second. I have no idea where the 5,8 come from, I would expect 6,9 instead.

Comment: sorry about that.. the answer on the back of the page was wrong and the question is correct

Answer (score 1):

Presumably the bottom varies uniformly between 3-9'.

For $h\in[0,6]$ the length of the surface water line is $h {40 \over 6}$.
For $h \in [6,9]$ the length of the surface water line is $40$.
Let $l(h) = \begin{cases} h {40 \over 6}, & h\in[0,6) \\
40, & h \in [6,9] \end{cases}$.

Then the volume of water is given by $v(h) = 20 \int_0^h l(x) dx$.